# What is the right format for label for multi label in fasttext?

Tags: python, machine-learning, fasttext

Currently I am working on Stack overflow tag prediction where I am using fasttext for text classification.

I wanted to know that what is the correct format for label for if label multiclass.

```
 1.) __label__toxic__label__racist__label__insult
2.)__label__toxic, __label__racist, __label__insult

3.)__label__toxic __label__racist __label__insult
4.)__label__toxic,__label__racist,__label__insult
```

So can someone tells me which one is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third is the correct format, as you can see in this [example file](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/data/cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz) from [FastText tutorial for text classification](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html):

> __label__sauce __label__cheese How much does potato starch affect a cheese sauce recipe?
>   __label__sauce __label__storage-lifetime __label__acidity __label__mayonnaise Regulation and balancing of readymade packed mayonnaise and other sauces