# Training data for unsupervised learning api

Tags: fasttext

I am trying to use the "crawl-300d-2M.vec" pre-trained model to cluster the documents for my projects. I am not sure what format the training data(train.txt) should be when i use

`ft_model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(input='train.txt',pretrainedVectors=path, dim=300)`

My corpus contains 10k documents. What I did was to put them all in a text file and feed it to train_unsupervised method. I did not get good results. Can someone explain what i am missing ? Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you tried and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979380/what-is-the-right-format-for-label-for-multi-label-in-fasttext/59980627#59980627

By the way, I'm not sure that fasttext is suitable for document classification/clustering. Usually it works well for sentences.

Comment: It is not essentially clustering but close. I am trying to find,for instance, if "This is an apple" and "fruit" has a high cosine similarity. I thought about finding and matching the vectors of "This is an apple" and "fruit" with fasttext. I am not sure though if I can use pre-trained word vectors for this or have to train my own vectors with my corpus.